# Why isn't my script working?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to set up a script for my website where a section of text in

tags changes depending on my link using `/file.php?s-id=1` but the script I am using isn't working. The database is named ftvo and the table is named seriesdb. I have attached a snippet of my code below just with the database password missing for security reasons:

```
<?php
$sId = $_GET['s-id'];
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "userpassword", "ftvo");
$sql = "
   SELECT id, series
   FROM seriesdb
   WHERE id = $sId
   LIMIT 1
";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$s = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>No Next Episode</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="color:#FF0000">SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTION</h1>
<a href="/"><h3>Home</h3></a>
<p>We apoligise but there is no more episodes of <? $s['series']; ?> currently available. Please check back later.</p>
<hr />
<p>This site is owned by <b>TechXtra Web Services</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can answer any questions regarding my mysql server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want *free* help, don't make it difficult for us

Comment: How is that difficult? Im simply asking someone to see if there is any errors in the script so I can diagnose the database itself.

Comment: Perhaps `<?php echo $s['series']; ?>`?

Comment: What does 'it isn't working' mean? Please give us a clue...

Comment: *not working* can mean an infinite number of things.

Comment: And for **grammar's sake** it's **"apologize"** as per [**Le Robert & Collins Senior Edition**](http://www.collins.co.uk) reference dict., page 1099 published 2006, eight edition, and not Google ;-) My trusty 'ol friend, is always by my side.

Comment: If the script had been read it would surely show what I am trying to achieve. Thanks for your contribution @Fred and I will spell check the document once I'm finished, the website is only currently in Alpha anyway.

Comment: i know what its trying to do, but not where it is failing...

Comment: @JWassall Grammar is so important, you wouldn't believe. Imagine if your doctor didn't know how to spell and gave you the wrong prescription? ;-) it's happened before. And you're welcome; I love good grammar, while reading a really good book. Cheers

Comment: The internet has breed a generational of people, that expect other's to do everything for them, for free, and to be grateful for the *privilege*.

Comment: @JWassall Did you not see the answers below? That mistake is evident. If it's not that, then it's most likely your DB that's at fault. Start with the basic troubleshooting steps. Unescaped or illegal chars., wrong length, encoding, the list goes on...

Comment: @Fred I'm usually good at my english, considering I was born and raised and still live in Britain but I did write that page at around midnight so I knew I would make mistakes, that's why I asked on here, to make sure I didn't have any more mistakes. I also have fixed the problem now. I did check my DB to ensure nothing was wrong there. Dagon I am always grateful for any help I receive and I only wanted someone to show me where I went wrong, i'm not a PHP pro or anything so sometimes I need help getting something right.

Comment: @JWassall I understand. I'm just a stickler for spelling/grammar. Being an editor for a printing firm for 10 years, has taken its toll (lol) I did put in the 3rd comment about the `echo` ;-)

Comment: @Fred I could never be an editor.. I'm not a fan of reading pages and pages of information and doing the job of a well written spelling and grammar program. I must have missed your comment when diegoperini answered.

Comment: @JWassall Never is a word that's not in "my" dictionary (lol) you can achieve anything you want, that's entirely up to you. Having to go over pages and pages of text/characters, one tends to pick up on little things. Novels are allowed a certain amount of spelling mistakes per thousand words, as opposed to let's say, restaurant menus which should be none. *Just thought I'd share that.* Cheers ;-) P.s.: I've seen millions of "characters" in my life, but apparently, I take the "cake". (grin)

Comment: @Fred I never knew novels even had spelling mistakes. I guess my mind just read the words as they should have been instead of what they actually were. Well I will admit that before I started web development I said to myself "I could never do this, it looks too complicated." That was before I spent around a month determined to learn as much as possible and it paid off.. I'm even making money off my services now.

Comment: @JWassall Some novels actually do contain mistakes, they are rather rare, but they nonetheless can contain some. Editors are not perfect and can miss the odd ones at times. Spell checkers don't always get it right neither; I never use them myself, and that is why I have my trusty dictionary by my side. It's a good feeling isn't it, making money at something you enjoy doing? Enjoy the ride, there's a lot of work out there. Take care, *Peace*.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `echo` here:

`<p>We apoligise but there is no more episodes of <? echo $s['series']; ?> currently available. Please check back later.</p>`

Comment: Thanks. Works great now. I was worried I'd messed up the database query.

Comment: @JWassall Right on, glad it was just that. Could've been worse, cheers

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<? $s['series']; ?>
```

to

```
<?= $s['series'] ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $s['series']; ?>
```

Comment: As said by diegoperini, I only needed to add `echo` after `<?` but thanks for your answer anyway.